# Data reader in C# just show one record in looping?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my looping here

```
string searchsynonymsID_ = "";
    do
                {
                    int count = reader.FieldCount;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        searchsynonymsID_ = reader["searchsynonymsID"].ToString();
                    }
                } while (reader.NextResult());
```

if I use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dr["searchsynonymsID"]);` the record is showing in loop.
I need parse the loop into a variable. how to do that?, currently its just show one record, I need rest record showing.

Comment: What type is your `searchsynonymsID_` and why you are using `count` here?? you might need to be more specific!!

Comment: You need to add then to a collection, like a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) or even a [Datatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: could any one fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<string> searchsynonymsIDs = new List<string>();
  do
    {
        int count = reader.FieldCount;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            searchsynonymsIDs.Add(reader["searchsynonymsID"].ToString());
        }
    } while (reader.NextResult());
```

Comment: your are awesome, but how to convert the result searchsynonymsIDs into variable? I need variable to run query delete, so the variable will be parameter.